# Unable to switch to gdm3 in 17.04

Tags: lightdm, gdm, display-manager

I'm trying to get the full gnome experience and I was trying to switch from lightdm to gdm3. I did this by changing `/etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

The problem is that, after closing the session, gdm3 never starts. After rebooting the system never shows the login screen and after a while I get the "default resolution" screen (which also doesn't work btw, since I can't select any of the options with the keyboard or the mouse).

I tried launching gdm3 from the console shell and it fails silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` does not work properly as you have discovered, but running the command `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` in 16.04 and later releases will cause gdm to reload its configuration upon the next reboot.

Open the terminal and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`. This will open up a new window allowing you to select either gdm or lightdm as the default login display manager.

Comment: Worked like a charm after rebooting. Thanks. 

Just logout didn't do it, since there was a warning after reconfigure:

gdm.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.

Comment: after choosing `gdm3` in the screen that appears after I type in the command, I get this error: `gdm.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.`

Comment: You have posted 3 questions about Ubuntu 17.04. Is this happening in 17.04 by any chance? If so, see this bug report: [gdm package tries to restart service and fails](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-pptp/+bug/1690953).