# Can't switch to gdm3 using sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

Tags: lightdm, gdm, display-manager

I was looking for a way to switch to `gdm3` from `lightdm`, when I found [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/927681/632192)
So I tried to apply it, and entered `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`, then a selection screen appeared with 2 options: `gdm3` and `lightdm`. It was the same screen that appeared during the installation of GNOME (using `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop && gnome-shell`). I chose `gdm3` then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then I got this error:

```
gdm.service is not active, cannot reload.
invoke-rc.d: initscript gdm3, action "reload" failed.
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that it just required a reboot to work.
But I still want to know the meaning of that error I got. Does anyone have any explanation?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

re: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` error message.

Just reboot and you should be running gdm3.

The error that you're receiving just means that gdm3 wasn't already running, so it couldn't reload it.

Comment: do you know what that error means though?

Comment: It just means that gdm3 wasn't already running, so it couldn't reload it. Kind of a bogus error.

Comment: this didn't work for me

Comment: @trust_words please start a new question and we'll try and help you.

Answer (score 22):

Use this `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` in place of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` this and then choose gdm3.

Comment: Can you please explain how would that make any difference? When either of them is used, options are shown to switch default DM.

Comment: But there is something different between both of them as I tried  it work, When I work on lightdm I use dpkg-reconfigure lightdm and on gdm use gdm in place of lightdm and it works without any error

Comment: I agree, you should specify the one you are using at the moment. Don't know why but it's always worked for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

Works for my WSL2 Ubuntu Desktop install - thanks:-

```sh
sudo systemctl start gdm3.service    
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Comment: Awesome as it does not need reboot

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a hack! You just need to type this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Then you will get the option to choose your display manager where you can choose GDM instead of LightDM.

Worked for me, hope it works for you too.

Comment: This does not answer the question after the Update but it may help future users.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo systemctl start gdm3.service    
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

So manually start gdm3, then reconfigure it and it stays working, even after a reboot.

(I know, weird, I'll update the answer if I work out what causes this)