# Gdm3 broken after trying to fix screen tearing issues on AMD stony

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, amd-graphics, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

Please pardon the typos as I am on my phone now that my computer is not working :-( .

I have a laptop with AMD stony processor . I recently tried changing 20-Radeon.conf to try to fix some awful Screen tearing that would happen when I plugged mDesktop broken after trying to fix screen tearing issues on AMD stonyy computer into an External monitor. I tried switching to light GBM but then my laptop screen failed to load. Then I tried switching back to GDM three but now my laptop screen freezes at the loading screen. There doesn’t seem to be a problem with my computer itself since when I open recovery mode I can access a shell just fine.

Here are some of the tutorials I followed:
[Can't switch to gdm3 using sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939353/cant-switch-to-gdm3-using-sudo-dpkg-reconfigure-gdm3)

[What is gdm3, kdm, lightdm? How to install and remove them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829108/what-is-gdm3-kdm-lightdm-how-to-install-and-remove-them)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Any assistance you could offer would be greatly appreciated!