# Ubuntu OS is not working

Tags: 20.04, startup, system

I changed Display manager from gdm3 to lightdm, then i removed lightdm using apt-get remove lightdm, then I rebooted computer, on startup it shows black screen that shows cmd.

The reason I installed lightdm is webcam and mic was not working

Machine: Thinkpad t450s
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
CPU: core I5 5th Gen

Comment: Have you re-enabled gdm3?

Comment: Also, welcome to AskUbuntu.  Please be sure to take our [tour] and read through the [FAQ] to better understand how this site works.

Comment: I am having the same issues. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to switch to gdm3 in17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927677/unable-to-switch-to-gdm3-in17-04)