# Have to manually start gmd3 after installing and uninstalling KDE Plasma

Tags: gnome, gdm, display-manager

Some months ago I installed KDE Plasma, didn't like it much and uninstalled it again. Now every time I start my laptop, a black screen comes up and asks for login name and password. After that I have to use `systemctl start gdm3` to start the GUI.

How can I make it start automatically as it used to?

Comment: You've not told us your Ubuntu product or release details; but did you return `gdm3` to being your chosen default greeter/dm?

Comment: Thanks guiverc... that was my problem :) Fixed it now after i found out how to choose the default

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to switch to gdm3 in17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927677/unable-to-switch-to-gdm3-in17-04)

Comment: Would you consider adding an answer to explain how you fixed it, for the benefit of future visitors?